# CSS - Whole div clickable but an area not

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a a block with some information in it. This div has a hidden button called `.remove`. When you principal click on that block it takes you to another side. When you enter the div with your mouse the button appears. And of course the button is clickable too. But my problem here is the button is **in** the a block, which means when i click the button it takes me to the other side too. I don't want that action. Is the a way with CSS or/and jQuery how to prevent the forwarding to another side when you click the button?

The HTML:

```
<a href="/asite">
    ...
    <input type="button" class="remove" value="Remove" />
    ...
</a>
```

Comment: maybe [preventdefault](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) is something that might help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the block - run the regular block code - except if you clicked the inner button

```
$('block-selector').on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('button-selector').length) {
    // Run block code.
  }
});
```

Now when you click the inner button the block code doesn't interfere.

Check out [this post](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) by Philip Walton on a similar issue which uses this technique

Answer (score 1):

Apply this to your button

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will stop your click bubbling up to it's containing div, which causes the click event on the div to occur.

More information: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Not working. See my updated answer. Maybe because the button is not linked but the whole parented block?

Comment: That should work, are you sure you changed `'button'` to `'.remove'` ?